# Codeigniter - call to undefined method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a project in Ci and I can't get it to recognize my check2() for some reason. CI keeps throwing Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::check2()

controller (Login.php)

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

 public function index() {
 // Page variables
 $page['title'] = "Analytics Login";  
 $this->load->view('header', $page); 
 $this->load->view('login');
 $this->load->view('footer');
 }

 public function verify() {

 $verifier = $this->load->model('Verifylogin_model');

 $username = $this->input->post('username');
 $password = $this->input->post('password');

 if((!$verifier->check2($username,$password))) {
 $this->load->view('login');
 } else {
 redirect('home', 'refresh'); 
 }
 }
}
```

Model (verifylogin_model.php)

```
<?php
Class Verifylogin_model extends CI_Model {

 function __construct() {
 parent::__construct();
    }

 public function check2($username, $password) {

 $this->db->select('user_id, user_email');
 $this->db->from('admin_users');
 $this->db->where('user_email', $username);
 $this->db->where('user_pass', md5($password));
 $this->db->limit(1);

 $results = $this->db->get();

 if ($results->num_rows() == 1) {
 return true;
 } else {
 return false;
 }
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

CI loader does'nt return the model instance, but the global CI instance.

You can use:

```
$this->load->model('Verifylogin_model');
$verifier = $this->Verifylogin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the model method in following manner

```
 $this->load->model('verifylogin_model');

 $this->verifylogin_model->check2();
```

Answer (score 1):

CI use "dependency injection" heavily. Loader is not a factory class which you can't get Verifylogin_model instance directly. In CI, you should call the model like the following example

```php
if (!$this->Verifylogin_model->check2($username, $password)) {
 /* your code */
}
```

Comment: Just a note, CI does'nt use DI - it uses global variables and service container. I wish it was using a proper DI container...